Display text and variables above WooCommerce cart block, and in cart items components
I am trying to display "Hello World $some_php_variable_related_to_cart" above the WooCommerce cart block (in a proper way, using WordPress and WooCommerce API), and to update $some_php_variable_related_to_cart value every time the cart changes.
And, same question, but in the CartLineItemRow component, next to the remove link.
This was easy to do with the legacy Cart Shortcode and related hooks, but unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation or any developer who knows how these blocks can be extended, or if it is possible at all. Can you help? :)

I could create a block (tutorial), but I couldn't automatically display it above the WooCommerce cart. I couldn't find how to update $some_php_variable_related_to_cart value every time the cart changes, either.
I could pass the PHP variable to the cart items thanks to woocommerce_store_api_register_endpoint_data (example). But I couldn't find how to display it in the CartLineItemRow component, next to the remove link, and update the display every time the cart changes.
